# UIViewcontroller not visible in my application

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In my application, I have two UIViewcontrollers , When I push from first page to the second page and vise versa its working fine for the fist time. When I push it for second time from first to the second page **the methods in the second page get called** but not navigate to the second page its still in first page.
Please correct me if I have made some mistake. Thanks in advance.

I have used the below code

```
MYviewcontroller* vc = [[MYviewcontroller alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: please provide some code how you push the view controllers

Comment: if using storyBoard please attach screenshot of it

Comment: I am not using storyBoard

Comment: arc? did you forget to release your vc?

Answer (score 0):

For UINavigationController to work properly you gotta **push**(to the next page) and **pop** (back to previous page) correctly.
I see your code are pushing the ViewController correctly.

You just gotta pop your second VC back to previous VC by calling

```
self.navigationController.popToViewController(vc,animated:true)
```